# formato de cadenas de texto android

Tags: android, android-studio, string

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy haciendo una consulta a una base de datos, la consulta me trae un valor tipo String con un formato tipo ###.###,## la pregunta que tengo son las siguientes:

1.- Como puedo eliminar las comas y puntos para usar esa data en una operacion matematica dentro de la app. (tomando en cuenta que el numero en cuestion puede tener decimales

2.- Como puedo lograr que un nuevo TextView despues de la operacion mantenga el formato que traigo?

Todo esto aplicado a un textWacther

```
saldito = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            saldo_despues.setText(addNumbers());
            int ncom1, ncom2;
            if(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString() != "" && saldoUsrAct.getText().length() > 0) {
                ncom2 = Integer.parseInt(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString());

            } else {
                ncom2 = 0;
            }
            if(ttmonto.getText().toString() != "" && ttmonto.getText().length() > 0) {
                    ncom1 = Integer.parseInt(ttmonto.getText().toString());
            } else {
                ncom1 = 0;
            }

            if(ncom1 > ncom2){
                saldo_despues.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE70822"));
            } else {
                saldo_despues.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }

        }
    };
    ttmonto.addTextChangedListener(saldito);



}



private String addNumbers() {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    if(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString() != "" && saldoUsrAct.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if(ttmonto.getText().toString() != "" && ttmonto.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(ttmonto.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }

    return Integer.toString(number1 - number2);
}

}
```

Este codigo me funciona por que no le he asigando el valor a uno de los textview, pero en el momento en que toma la variable que traigo desde la base de datos, me genera el error, como puedo hacer para trabajar con las cadenas que traigo.

Aqui tengo otra forma que tampoco me funciona:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String convertedString = new DecimalFormat("##.###.###,##").format(Double.parseDouble(addNumbers()));
            saldo_despues.setText(convertedString);
            double ncom1, ncom2;
            if(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString() != "" && saldoUsrAct.getText().length() > 0) {
                ncom2 = Double.parseDouble(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString());

            } else {
                ncom2 = 0;
            }
            if(ttmonto.getText().toString() != "" && ttmonto.getText().length() > 0) {
                    ncom1 = Double.parseDouble(ttmonto.getText().toString());
            } else {
                ncom1 = 0;
            }

            if(ncom1 > ncom2){
                saldo_despues.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE70822"));
            } else {
                saldo_despues.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }

        }
    };
    ttmonto.addTextChangedListener(saldito);



}



private String addNumbers() {
    double number1;
    double number2;
    if(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString() != "" && saldoUsrAct.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if(ttmonto.getText().toString() != "" && ttmonto.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Double.parseDouble(ttmonto.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }

    return Double.toString(number1 - number2);
}
```

Ok, quiero darle formato a un TextView, ya que ya me estoy figurando como poder traerme desde el servidor, un string que no necesite ser modificado de ninguna manera (un poco rudimentario pero puede funcionar), lo que necesito es saber como colocarle formato al textview para que me muestre los datos formateados de la forma que deseo.

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Supongo que quieres formatear el resultado del metodo `addNumbers`. Puedes lograrlo con `DecimalFormat` pasando al constructor el formato:

```
private String addNumbers() {
    double number1;
    double number2;
    if(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString() != "" && saldoUsrAct.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if(ttmonto.getText().toString() != "" && ttmonto.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Double.parseDouble(ttmonto.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }

    NumberFormat nformat = new DecimalFormat("##,###,###.##");
    return nformat.format(number1 - number2);
}
```

Comment: Se puede explicar porque el voto negativo?

Comment: No se por que el voto negativo, la verdad es que no lo coloque yo. Lo que si puedo decirte es que se me crashea la app con esta solucion

Comment: Que error te lanza?

Comment: El error era mio, pues queria que en vez de comas fueran puntos los separadores de miles, pero ya vi que funciona como es debido. Hay forma de que los miles los separe con punto?

Comment: No se puede. Las , son las separadores de grupo y el . separador de decimal.